# How does a recursive call work in the function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion, methods

The purpose of this algorithm is to return an array which is split into smaller two-dimensional arrays inside of it. The length of each internal array is defined by `size`.
How does the recursive call with `.slice()` method work here?
How does it make the function return an array split into smaller sub-arrays? 
I can't understand this solution.

```
function chunkyArrayInGroups(arr, size){
    if(arr.length <= size){
        return [arr];
    } else {
        return [arr.slice(0, size)].concat(chunkyArrayInGroups(arr.slice(size), size));
    }
}
```

Comment: What a beautiful function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When going up the callstack, chunks get sliced away from the arrays front (`.slice(size)`):

```
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> [2, 3, 4, 5] -> [4, 5] -> []
```

Now at every recursive call there exists an intermediate value holding the sliced away part (`.slice(0, size)`):

```
                   [0, 1]             [2, 3]       [4, 5]
```

Now the chunked away parts get concatenated together when the stack unwinds:

```
                   [0, 1]           [2, 3]        [[4, 5]]
                   [0, 1]          [[2, 3], [4, 5]]
                  [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```